# Taking away Strikethrough in VIM

Tags: vim

I have strikethrough working in vim, but I want to unstrikethrough a line after I put the strikethrough on it. Here's the line in my .vimrc

```
command! -range -nargs=0 Strikethrough   call s:CombineSelection(<line1>, <line2>, '0336')
```

Here's the function.

```vim
function! s:CombineSelection(line1, line2, cp)
    execute 'let char = "\u'.a:cp.'"'
    execute a:line1.','.a:line2.'s/\%V[^[:cntrl:]]/&'.char.'/ge'
endfunction
```

Comment: The "strikethrough" logic is in your `CombineSelection()` function. How can we tell you how to reverse it if we don't know how you implemented it in the first place?

Comment: Thanks, justed added it to the question